# Binary chop search algorithm in C

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to write a binary chop search function in C and having some issues. First of all, after finding the midpoint values, the function isn't even entering any of the if loops.

The function is this:

```
   int binarychopsearch(int i, int *array, int min, int N) {

min = 0;
int max = N - 1;
printf("Min = %d, Max = %d\n", min, max);
printf("i = %d\n", i);



        int mid = (min + max)/2;
        //printf("midpoint = %d\n", mid);
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n", mid, array[mid]);
  if (i < array[mid]) {
        printf("in this loop\n");
        printf("i = %d, array[mid] = %d\n", i, array[mid]);
        // key is in lower subset
        return binarychopsearch(i, array, min, mid - 1);
        }


  else if (i > array[mid]) { 
      printf("in the greater than loop\n");
      printf("i = %d, array[mid] = %d\n", i, array[mid]);
      return binarychopsearch(i, array, mid + 1, max);
      }

  else 

  //if (i = array[mid]) {

        return mid;
}
```

I'm not including the main where the input values come from as I think the issue is in this function. It is compiling and running, but not entering the loops so not finding the location of the "i" value. I'm pretty stuck on this as I can't see where it's going wrong.

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please submit properly formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

If `i` is larger (or equal) to `array[mid]` then you *unconditionally* return from the function. Instead you then should check the next condition, and then if that is false as well you know you have found the value you were looking for.

So it should look something like

```
if (i < array[mid])
{
    ...
}
else if (i > array[mid])
{
    ...
}
else
    return mid;
```

---

There are other problems with your code as well.

Lets say you have the following array

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

and you are looking for the value `5`.

The calls will be like this:

```
| Call# | min | N | max | mid | array[mid] |
|   1   |  0  | 5 |  4  |  2  |    3       |
|   2   |  3  | 4 |  3  |  3  |    4       |
|   3   |  4  | 3 |  2  |  2  |    3       |
|   4   |  3  | 2 |  1  |  2  |    3       |
|   5   |  3  | 1 |  0  |  1  |    2       |
|   6   |  2  | 0 | -1  |  1  |    2       |
.
.
.
```

It's quite clear that this will not end well. In fact, you will soon end up with *negative* index, and that leaves you in the territory of *undefined behavior*.

I suggest you create your *own* table like this, on paper, when trying to fix your algorithm, for both cases of recursion.

If you **don't** call the recursive function with `max` but with `N` instead, i.e.

```
return binarychopsearch(i, array, mid + 1, N);
```

then you will have the following calls

```
| Call# | min | N | max | mid | array[mid] |
|   1   |  0  | 5 |  4  |  2  |    3       |
|   2   |  3  | 5 |  4  |  3  |    4       |
|   3   |  4  | 5 |  4  |  4  |    5       |
```

So the third call found the number, and returns the index `4`.

You should also change the first call:

```
return binarychopsearch(i, array, min, mid);
```

Comment: What should I have instead?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @user3306583 Updated my answer with some example code

Comment: ok that seemed to put me in an infinite loop. I'll update the code in the original question so you can see what I did there...

Comment: @user3306583 One problem is that you pass `max` in the second recursive call, when you should use `N`.

Comment: even though I've declared max = N - 1?

Comment: @user3306583 Yes, that means that every recursive call the max will be smaller and smaller. So if you start searching a 10 entry array, the second iteration will search a 9 entry array, the third recursion an 8 entry array, etc. It goes for *both* recursions.

Comment: Yes I see that when it runs but when I replace it with N, the infinite loop stays but it isn't updating the midpoint. Biggest issue seems to be that it isn't really comparing i to the midpoint value

Comment: @user3306583 Please see my updated answer again, have added a table showing the calls.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm having trouble understanding what you're telling me though.

Comment: @user3306583 If you call the function recursively with a decreasing value of `N`, then you *do* have an infinite loop, and will soon have a *negative* value of `mid` which you use to index `array`. If you use `N` in the second call (when `i > array[mid]`) then you will find the value `5` (from my example) at the third call to the function (two levels of recursions).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when `i >= array[mid]`: you systematically return -1: use `esle if`

```
if(i < array[mid])
{}
else if(i > array[mid])
{}
else // i == array[mid]
{}
```

Comment: Technically speaking it is not a "loop", rather an if "statement" ;)